# Start reading a line after n characters

Tags: java

I am making a program that take the data from internet, more specifically this url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/eng-england/master/2017-18/1-premierleague-i.txt

I want to calculate the standings based on the result, but I'm struggling with reading the file since I haven't figured out how to get the result in the middle of the line. I noticed there is a certain pattern in the text such as the results are always written after 27 characters, beginning with a white space but I don't know how to implement that into my code in order to extract the results and I also wonder if there were any better way to achieve this (I tried using delimiter but it didn't work).
Therefore, any help or advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: Use `BufferedReader.readLine()` and then take `line.substring(27)`

Comment: Do you have specific examples, like a line of data you're parsing and what the outputs should be?  Try looking into [`String.substring(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) and [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) (replaceAll is preferable if you have a pattern that you're matching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result with a matcher, see code below. You just need read the file line by line

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mydata = "Arsenal FC               4-3  Leicester City";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        String result = "";
        if (matcher.find()) {
            result = matcher.group();
            mydata = mydata.replace(result, "#");
        }
        String[] dataSplit = mydata.split("#");

        HashMap<String, String> match = new HashMap<>();

        match.put("local", dataSplit[0].trim());
        match.put("visitor", dataSplit[1].trim());
        match.put("result", result);

        System.out.println(match.get("local"));
        System.out.println(match.get("result"));
        System.out.println(match.get("visitor"));
}
```

Output:

`Arsenal FC
4-3
Leicester City`

When you have the result you can replace it for a # for example, then split that line by # and you get both teams. From here is easy to create a map or a json with both teams and the match result

Comment: Would you mind elaborate more about the latter part after getting the result? I'm kinda new to Java so I'm still not very good at data processing very much

Answer (score 0):

Just use a combination of `substring` and `trim` and a bit of parsing.

```
public Map<String, Integer> getScore(String line) {
  String host = line.substring(2,25).trim();
  String guest = line.substring(32).trim();
  String[] scores = line.substring(25, 32).trim().split("-");
  Map<String,Integer> matchScore = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  matchScore.put(host, Integer.valueOf(scores[0]));
  matchScore.put(guest, Integer.valueOf(scores[1]))
  return matchScore;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it said: Cannot resolve method 'of(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)'

Comment: @neX This is because you don't use Java 8, but an older version. I've adapted for Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can skip *n* characters with `skip(n)` when reading from your `BufferedReader`, and get the rest of the line with `line()` afterwards.

> **[skip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip(long))**
>
> ```
> public long skip(long n)
>       throws IOException
> ```
>
> Skips characters.